# Function behavior dependent on the calling class

Tags: design-patterns, c++

I have a base class B and several children classes of it.

Every children B1, B2, B3... has a method that calls a method M of another class C.

Class C has a component D (implementing an interface, think strategy pattern)

Method M calls a method N of D.

I want the behavior of N to depend on what class (B1, B2, B3) is calling in the first place.

What would be the best way to do that?
Maybe the structure of the classes needs to be changed.

Bjarne Stroustrup in his C++ book suggests that the best way to handle a caller-dependent behavior is to use polymorphism and have a different behavior for each class B1 B2... But I cannot use this solution here. B and its children are not aware of D.

Comment: This is too abstract. Show us a specific  example of your code, and describe what "I want the behavior of N to depend on what class (B1, B2, B3) is calling" means within the context of that code.  Offhand, knowing nothing else, it sounds like what you want is either a Factory or Abstract Factory.

Comment: Could you not have a callback from N to the B children?

Comment: I agree with @RobertHarvey. Way too many letters to keep track of for us to make sense of this question, and the solution may depend on what you are actually doing.

Comment: What you are describing sounds like D should implement the Visitor Pattern, or that N should be a template method.  However, you'll have to explain more closely why polymorphism won't cut it here. Ideally, model the class hierarchy in example code, define which parts can be modified, and write a test case that would verify a solution to your problem. As it stands, your question is just underspecified.

Comment: I agree that it is too abstract. Much also depends on how the behaviour of N should vary depending on which class is calling.

Comment: I don't think this is "too abstract" just draw a picture and everything is clear. But there is a question : Something needs to know which implementation of D to call based on which B. Can this be C? Or can some kind of "Factory" class build the classes so that each B is wired up with right implementation of D?

Comment: I think the visitor pattern is actually what I need.
Just for the record, the factory pattern won't work, because there isn't a 1-to-1 correspondence between B and D.